# Emacs org-mode link formatting

Tags: regex, emacs, org-mode

I use org-mode in emacs to created structured documents but one of the features I'm really interested in and would like to use for other areas are the way links are formatted. Say for example I want to create a link to another location take google for example I could simply write

`[[http://www.google.com][To Google]]` and as soon as I complete the second square bracket it will change to look like `To Google` but the underlying structure remains in tact, if I remove the second bracket it simply expands again.

I have downloaded the source code but I cant seem to find where this has been implemented. If anyone knows how it has been achieved I would be very grateful for an explanation. I would imagine It could be replicated with regular expressions but im rather clueless.

Thanks

Comment: I did a wild guess and googled "orgmode overlays links" and found a question 7864985 on stackoverflow where a commentator said that org-mode links are implemented by means of "overlays" (wihch is an technique of emacs to do various display tricks (like eg org-mode liniks and dropdown-boxes)). Maybe this info helps you chasing the implementation further? good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i'll investigate :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can digg from here: `C-h f org-activate-bracket-links RET`.

`C-h f org-toggle-link-display RET` and `C-h f org-link-display-format RET` are also good starting points.

Comment: My org-mode must be out of date since I can't seem to find that function. Thanks you your help buddy :)